# xlwings is not returning tuple

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlwings

I have a function that I am using in xlwings which returns 3 values as a tuple. I would like to return all of these values to 3 cells in excel without calling the function 3 times as the calculations are made together. Here is some mock code:

```
@xw.func   
def pull_data_and_calc(search_key):    
    betas = calculations()  # calculations returns a tuple of size 3   
    beta = betas[0]  
    beta_up = betas[1]  
    beta_down = betas[2]  
    return beta, beta_up, beta_down
```

Anyone who has calculated betas before knows that total beta is calculated alongside beta_up and beta_down so it would be highly inefficient to run functions for each beta calculation. I apologize for not including more code but it is impossible for compliance reasons and this is relatively similar to the output.

Running this function in excel only shows the beta value and I cannot get it to display beta_up or beta_down. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you simply pressed ENTER to apply the formula in excel. If not, nevermind.

When you enter the function into excel, do it with three cells selected, like this:[image]

Then press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter the formula as an array formula. This will apply the formula to all three cells as an array, and allow output of multiple return values from your python function.